# Android hiding markers not selected

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a list view for this project to have the user select a location and they are able to open a map view of this location with a marker pointing to it.  Currently I have 4 markers all of which are working but is there a way to hide all of the markers that were not chosen by the user?  These are my markers I am using in the  MapsActivity

```
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.1983, -85.4089)).title("University"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.2223, -85.3753)).title("Mall"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.2217, -85.3808)).title("Target"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.160175, -85.371147)).title("Walmart"));
```

This is the code I am using in the MainActivity to send the user to the map activity when an item from the list is chosen Right now it is just setup for the mall until I get it working.  It shows the map centered at 0,0 and all 4 markers over in the United States.  (part 2 of my troubles)  When I try to put mMap code in the main activity it throws errors at me

```
    if (id == R.id.map_it && tasknumber == 1) {

        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextScreen);
        return true;
    }
```

I am trying to also set the map up so it centers the map on the markers.  In the mapsactivity class I was trying to use the code below its throwing an error at (latLng, 10) saying newLatLngBounds can not be applied to

```
    private void setUpMap() {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(40.1983, -85.4089);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLng, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear your Map and add a marker on which user has clicked in listview

```
mMap.clear();
```

Implemnt onItemClick listener :

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    addMarker(position);
}
```

Add method which will add marker on Map based on Listview index where user clicked :

```
public void addMarker(int index) {
    // clear previous markers on Map
    mMap.clear();

    switch(index) {
        case 0 : mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.1983, -85.4089)).title("University"));
                break;
        case 1 : mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.2223, -85.3753)).title("Mall"));
                break;
        case 2 : mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.2217, -85.3808)).title("Target"));
                break;
        case 3 : mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40.1983, -85.4089)).title("University"));
                break;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide/show your marker using setVisiblity.

Please check below code for your reference.

```
 Marker mMarker= gMap.addMarker(newMarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("MyPlace").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_pin)).draggable(true));
mMarker.setVisible(false);
```